# Text form Category Name in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, blogs, categories

In a Text-Widget of my Wordpress blog, I want to display the subcategory name of a specific main category of the latest post. Like:

TITLE: Category_1.1 Name

POST Categories: Category_1, Category_1.1, Category_2

.. the Title should automatically be updated when a new post has been added

Comment: You can do so by having get post meta for specific id and inside foreach loop.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions or directions are off-topic.